# CSS Transform over layer that already has tansform

Tags: css, transform, css-transforms

I have left and right sliding panels that are animated with TranslateX.

I am also using the headroom jQuery plugin which drops down a top nav when the user scrolls up using Translate Y.

The issue is the header is not visible when the page scrolls up if the transform is declared on the wrapper div.

If `transform: translateX(0px);` is removed from wrapper in firebug, the header is fixed when the page scrolls up. If it is present, the header seems to be static at the top of the page despite having a position: fixed attribute.

BASIC HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <header>
  </header>
</div>
```

CSS FOR SIDEBARS AND WRAPPER:

```
#left-sidebar{
  background-color:#8BA6BC;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;left:0;
  width:80%;
  height:100%;
  z-index:20;
  overflow:auto;
  transform:translateX(-100%);
  -moz-transform:translateX(-100%);
  -webkit-transform:translateX(-100%);
  transition:-moz-transform .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition:-moz-transform .25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform .25s ease-in-out;
}
#left-sidebar-handler.open ~ #left-sidebar{
  transform:translateX(0);
  -moz-transform:translateX(0);
  -webkit-transform:translateX(0);
}
#right-sidebar{
  background-color:#8BA6BC;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  width:80%;
  height:100%;
  z-index:20;
  overflow:auto;
  transform:translateX(100%);
  -moz-transform:translateX(100%);
  -webkit-transform:translateX(100%);
  transition:-moz-transform .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition:-moz-transform .25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform .25s ease-in-out;
}
#right-sidebar-handler.open ~ #right-sidebar{
  transform:translateX(0);
  -moz-transform:translateX(0);
  -webkit-transform:translateX(0);
}
#wrapper{
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  min-height:100%;
  height:auto !important;
  height:100%;
  margin-bottom:-45px;
  z-index:5;
  transform:translateX(0);
  -moz-transform:translateX(0);
  -webkit-transform:translateX(0);
  transition:-moz-transform .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition:-moz-transform .25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform .25s ease-in-out;
}
#left-sidebar-handler.open ~ #wrapper{
   transform:translateX(80%);
  -moz-transform:translateX(80%);
  -webkit-transform:translateX(80%);
}
#right-sidebar-handler.open ~ #wrapper{
  transform:translateX(-80%);
  -moz-transform:translateX(-80%);
  -webkit-transform:translateX(-80%);
}
```

CSS FOR HEADER:

```
html.signed-in header{
  position:fixed;
  z-index:999;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  min-height:46px;
  line-height:46px;
  background-color:#8BA6BC;
  color:#fff;
}
html.signed-in header.headroom{
  -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 200ms linear;
  -moz-transform 200ms linear;
  transition:transform 200ms linear;
}
html.signed-in header.headroom--pinned{
  -webkit-transform:translateY(0%);
  -ms-transform:translateY(0%);
  -moz-transform:translateY(0%);
  transform:translateY(0%);
}
html.signed-in header.headroom--unpinned{
  -webkit-transform:translateY(-100%);
  -ms-transform:translateY(-100%);
  -moz-transform:translateY(-100%);
  transform:translateY(-100%);
}
```

Comment: It seems as though adding the translate to the wrapper makes the header translate relative to the wrapper instead of the viewport window. However, when the sidebars slide out, the header needs to also slide with the wrapper.

Comment: I believe this also describes the issue: http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2011/09/12/un-fixing-fixed-elements-with-css-transforms/